# Why is Raspberry Pi 3B / 3B+'s CPU temperature precision 0.538°C?

Tags: temperature

While monitoring CPU temperature from `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`, I noticed that the minimal step is exactly 0.538°C. This is the same on both Pi 3 B and Pi 3 B+, and I suppose that it applies to Pi 3 A+. Why is it this value?

Comment: How are you calculating that exactly? i.e. how do you get from the contents of `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` to deg C? Are you sure the number is not 0.538??  If so, please edit your question.

Comment: @Seamus The number fetched from that path is exactly 1000*temperature (in Celsius).

Comment: Yes, that's true. But the smallest incremental change I see on my system is `538` (or, `0.538 degC`). I was asking you to confirm the value posted in your question is really `.528` and not `.538`.

Comment: @Seamus That might be a typo. Let me re-check later.

Comment: @Seamus Yeah you're right. It's a typo and indeed the step is 0.538°C.

Comment: That's good... if we had different "quantums", it would be harder to figure what was going on! I upvoted your question (+1) as it's a good one, IMHO, and it's the the first mention of it I've seen anywhere. And that would make this a discoverery  And as you have made the discovery, I feel you should get to name it :)  What will you call it? "iBug's Quantum" ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to go off-script a bit, and supply an incomplete answer. I am doing this in the hope that it will help "smoke out" a bit of knowledge on the proprietary CPU used in the Raspberry Pi, namely the range and resolution of the built-in temperature sensor. I've searched in vain for these two values for the past 30 minutes; if they're "published", they seem to be well-hidden (either that, or my Google searches are lame :)

The OP's question can be answered with a formula for quantization error:

Q = R/2<sup>N</sup>

Where:

Q = quantum, or step size

R = sensor range (max temp - min temp)

N = # bits used to represent the temperature reading

Consider for example a temp sensor with a range of 180 degF, where the temp readings are encoded as an 8-bit value:

Q = 180/2<sup>8</sup> = 0.703 degF

Which simply says that as the real (analog) temperature changes, the digital representation of that temperature will "jump" in increments of 0.703 degF.

If we know the R and N values for the RPi's internal CPU temp sensor, the Q value will be 0.538 degC.

Comment: You're seeking something that's proprietary to Broadcom and unlikely to be published anywhere.

Comment: @Dougie: I figured as much. But hackers are resourceful people, and if they come by the information honestly, then that's all well and good, and as it should be.

Answer (score 2):

The measuring range should extend over the full operating temperature range of the chip, and an 8 bit DAC presents minimal difficulty in fabrication, so is likely to be an 8 bit number. 0.528 * 256 = 135.168 deg. There will be a fair bit of tolerance on individual chips, if it was nominally 0.546875 (7.5% error, quite typical of untrimmed silicon) it would correspond to a range of 140 deg C, or -40 (typical lower limit for commercial semiconductors) to + 100 deg C, a reasonably safe maximum.

So I would suggest that it is the value of 1 LSB of an 8 bit uncalibrated DAC crudely measuring a typical working temperature range for the silicon.